# "Int should be Void -> Int" when comparing two integers

Tags: haxe

So this is a new one for me. When I try to compare 2 integers, the error tells me that Int should be Void -> Int, which is something I have never even seen before.

The code:

```
public static function whenTouchEnds(event:TouchEvent){
        for (item in currentTouches){
            if (item.getId == event.touchPointID){
                currentTouches.remove(item);
                trace("removed touch");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Following the Haxe documentation, I also tried:

```
public static function whenTouchEnds(event:TouchEvent){
        for (item in currentTouches){
            if (item.getId == event.touchPointID) break;
        }
    }
```

And for the sake of trail and error (hobby programmer here) even tried:

```
public static function whenTouchEnds(event:TouchEvent){
        for (item in currentTouches){
            var itemID:Int = item.getId;
            var touchID:Int = event.touchPointID;
            if (itemID == touchID){
                currentTouches.remove(item);
                trace("removed touch");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

They all gave me the same error message "Int should be Void -> Int". Here is the Touch class I created which returns an Integer with the getId function:

```
class Touch
{
    public var id:Int = 0;
    public var xPos:Int = 0;
    public var yPos:Int = 0;

    public function new(Id:Int, X:Int, Y:Int) 
    {
        id = Id;
        xPos = X;
        yPos = Y;
    }

    public function getX() : Int
    {
        return (xPos);
    }

    public function getY() : Int
    {
        return (yPos);
    }

    public function getId() : Int
    {
        return (id);
    }
}
```

I'm not looking for a simple solution, but rather an explanation of what I am missing here. The more I learn, the better!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is this line:

```
if (item.getId == event.touchPointID)
```

Since there's no parentheses, you're not actually [*calling*](https://haxe.org/manual/expression-function-call.html) the `getId()` function here - you're comparing it to an integer (which doesn't make sense). Try this instead:

```
if (item.getId() == event.touchPointID)
```

`Void -> Int` is Haxe's notation for a [function type](https://haxe.org/manual/types-function.html), specifically a function that takes no parameters (`Void`) and returns an integer. You're comparing such a function to an `Int`, hence the error message "`Int` should be `Void -> Int`".

---

A small code style critique: the `get*` functions in your `Touch` class don't really seem to serve any purpose, the variables are public anyway. If you ever want to do something more complex than just returning the variable in a getter function, you might want to look into using [properties](https://haxe.org/manual/class-field-property.html) instead.

Comment: Gosh... I've taken a break from programming for about a year or so, yet I keep making the same damn mistakes again haha. I knew it was something simple like this, but in the past I've been working with Unity's C#, which error messages are more clear. Thanks!